# What's the Keyboard Shortcut to archive an email message in the Windows 10 Mail app?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mail-app

I can delete an email message with the delete key, but there isn't an archive button on the keyboard. What's the Keyboard Shortcut to archive an email message in the Windows 10 Mail app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just press the BACKSPACE key. :)

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-mail-and-calendar-apps-for-windows-10-f36c75c3-9e1f-433d-9808-75b079b57e7b

Comment: That's remove not archive

Comment: I just press backspace and the email disappears from my "inbox" folder and appears in my "archive" folder. The documentation confirms it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-mail-and-calendar-apps-for-windows-10-f36c75c3-9e1f-433d-9808-75b079b57e7b

Comment: That only works in the reading pane.  If you are responding to a windows notification and eager to alt-tab away, you can't just hit backspace first to throw the message into the archive.  NOPE.  You have to move the mouse to a little square that reads "archive", and click it, to dismiss the message and not deal with it again. (per https://support.office.com/en-us/article/archive-in-outlook-for-windows-25f75777-3cdc-4c77-9783-5929c7b47028)